# Where do Chazal refer to Rus and Naomi as birds?

Tags: sources-mekorot, animals, historical-figures, book-of-ruth

Where is the Chazal that refers to Rus and Naomi (Na'ama?) as shnei preidos tovos - two good birds?

Comment: chazal, thanks for the question, and welcome to the site. I hope you stick around and enjoy it. Your question would be improved if you'd include in it anything you recall about this _maamar chazal_. Also, please consider [registering](http://mi.yodeya.com/users/login) your [account](http://mi.yodeya.com/users/1474), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features,

Answer (score 9):

The Talmud refers to Rut the Moabite and Naamah the Ammonite (King Shlomo's great-grandmother and wife respectively) as such at the very top of [Bava Kamma 38b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=38b&format=pdf).

> ויאמר ה' (אל משה) אל תצר את מואב ואל תתגר בם מלחמה וכי מה עלה על דעתו של משה לעשות מלחמה שלא ברשות אלא נשא משה ק"ו בעצמו אמר ומה מדינים שלא באו אלא לעזור את מואב אמרה תורה צרור את המדינים והכיתם אותם מואבים עצמן לא כל שכן אמר לו הקב"ה לא כשעלתה על דעתך עלתה על דעתי **שתי פרידות טובות יש לי להוציא מהן רות המואביה ונעמה העמונית**

Comment: There is also "שתי **ברכות טובות** יש לי להבריך בך רות המואביה ונעמה העמונית" on [Yevamos 63a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=63&format=pdf).