# Rashi on Righteous Kings: Omissions

Tags: rashi, malchut-royalty, melachim-kings-book-of, book-of-chronicles, masechet-yevamot

[Inspired by Jake's comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27922/what-was-so-good-about-naamah-the-ammonite)

Rashi to [Yebamoth 63a](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=yevamos&daf=63a&go=Go), describing Naamah the Ammonitess' prolific progeny (which began in the Davidic line with her son, Rehoboam), mentions Hezekiah, Asa, and Jehoshaphat, whom he lists as 'wholly righteous'. What about [Jotham](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et25b27.htm) and [Josiah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et25b34.htm)<sup>1</sup>?

Jotham has no stated faults, other than the [high places](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et09b15.htm), but [Asa](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et09a15.htm) and [Jehoshaphat](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et09a22.htm) also have this fault. [Josiah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et25b35.htm) may have erred by not heeding the word of God from the mouth of Pharaoh Necho, but each of the 3 mentioned kings made mistakes too. [Hezekiah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et09b20.htm) showed off his wealth to a Babylonian king, ([allusion in Chronicles](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et25b32.htm)). [Asa](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et25b16.htm) imprisoned an seer for rebuking him, and consulted physicians about a foot disease, instead of turning towards God. [Jehoshaphat](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et25b19.htm) attempted to ally with the wicked Northern Monarchs [multiple](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et25b20.htm) times.

**Why does Rashi leave out Jotham and Josiah?** are there flaws in them that are not stated in-text? Is there something exceptional about Hezekiah, Asa, and Jehoshaphat that sets them apart even from other righteous kings?

---

<sup>1. [Amaziah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et25b25.htm) turned to idols and was deposed. [Uziah/Azariah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et25b26.htm) was stricken with leprosy for a misguided attempt at seizing the priesthood, and he lived out his days in this state, which I could accept as meaning he was not fully forgiven.</sup>

Comment: Actually, from a Midrashic perspective, omitting Josiah is more surprising, as [Vayiqra Rabah 30:3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/ויקרא_רבה_ל_ג), and [Yalqut Shim'oni on Tehilim 102 (Remez 855)](http://www.tsel.org/torah/yalkutsh/tehilim.html#A2229), mention him, along with the other three, as one of the righteous decedents of David.

Comment: Radak to chron 27 says that maybe Jotham refused to go to the Temple because of what had befallen his father and he instead used the high places. According that, Jotham would have been perpetually sinning, as opposed to other kings occasional faults. This interpretation is very hard to acccept though, given the juxtaposion between he and the nation, who in kings clearly uses the high places during his reign. Additionally, the wholeidea is based on the phrase in the verse that says he was like his father, except he didnt go into the temple, which pretty clearly alludes to Uziah's mistake.

Comment: Also, on Sukkah 45b Simeon ben Yohai says that with Jotham's, (not Hezekiah, Asa, or Jehoshaphat's), help, he and his son could attone for all of the sins in the world, from beginning to end, which i think speaks pretty clearly to Jotham's righteousness.

Comment: I love how you (meaning mechon-mamre) called bamos 'high places'

Comment: @Matt they were just personal altars to God right?

Comment: @BabySeal yes, and I'm sure you knew that, but reading the chapter or your question without knowing that is a bit funny: it sounds like there's a sin to leave the country lansdscape not leveled flated

Comment: In a way, this question is asked by the Rashash (R' Shmuel Strashun), although he doesn't answer it. He points out that Rashi (Sukkah 45b, sv. יותם בן עוזיהו) declares Yotam to have been completely righteous, to have exemplified the mitzva of honouring one's father and of having been possessed of greater humility than any other king. He notes that Rashi doesn't mention Yotam here (Yevamot 63a), but doesn't suggest why.

Comment: Rabeinu Chananel on Sukkah says that Jotham did not receive any of his merits' rewards in this world.

Comment: @ShimonbM why doesn't the Rashash mention Josiah either though? because rash doesn't explicitly praise him?