# Rashi on Righteous Kings: Order

Tags: rashi, malchut-royalty, masechet-yevamot

[Inspired by Jake's comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27922/what-was-so-good-about-naamah-the-ammonite)

Rashi to [Yebamoth 63a](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=yevamos&daf=63a&go=Go), describing Naamah the Ammonitess' prolific progeny (which began in the Davidic line with her son, Rehoboam), mentions Hezekiah, Asa, and Jehoshaphat, in that order, followed by Isaiah.

[Chronologically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Genealogy_of_the_kings_of_Israel_and_Judah.svg), the correct order would be Asa, Jehoshaphat, and Hezekiah. Listing Hezekiah last would also make sense because he was [a contemporary of](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et1001.htm) Isaiah, who is the only prophet listed as descending from Naamah, and who follows the 'kings' section of Rashi's piece.

**Why does Rashi list the righteous kings out of order?**

Comment: For what it's worth, the three are mentioned in the same order as Rashi does in [Yalqut Shim'oni on Tehilim 102 (Remez 855)](http://www.tsel.org/torah/yalkutsh/tehilim.html#A2229), but chronologically in [Vayiqra Rabah 30:3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/ויקרא_רבה_ל_ג).

Comment: In the Yalkut Hezekiah is the only King out of order. We do Know that he was truly exceptional and was very nearly the Messiah.

Comment: The sefer המקום מרחק on Yevamos asks this question on Rashi and does not offer an answer. Source: http://daf-yomi.com/BookFiles.aspx?type=1&id=291